# Get actually type from map with generic keys and values

Tags: scala, generics, scala-collections

First some Scala code sample:

```
trait Key[+T]
trait Value[+T]

case class StringKey(key: String) extends Key[String]
case class IntKey(key: Int) extends Key[Int]

case class StringValue(value: String) extends Value[String]
case class IntValue(value: Int) extends Value[Int]

case class ValueHolder(sources: Map[Key[_], Value[_]]) {
  def processSources(): Unit = {
    sources.map{ case (key, value) =>
      // get actual key and value, and process
    }
  }
}
```

Basically I have a map from generic keys to generic values, and I need to iterate over the key-value pairs and operate on the actual objects. For example, I want to operate on a `StringValue` object if the current value is actually a  `StringValue`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Given JVM type erasure for generics I don't think it is possible that way. But if you wrap your key and value in an additional classes anyway, why not store the type information there as well?

Comment: @SergGr I think he already doing that Wrapping thing. I posted working solution. I appreciate ur advice if my and is lacking anything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Using Pattern matching or collecting the result with Partial function when `StringValue` occurs.

First, I think you missed that `StringKey extends Key[String]`, covariance of `T` and etc ...

Below code tells what is required.

```
trait Key[+T]

trait Value[+T]

case class StringKey(key: String) extends Key[String]
case class IntKey(key: Int) extends Key[Int]

case class StringValue(value: String) extends Value[String]
case class IntValue(value: Int) extends Value[Int]
```

Assume above case

```
case class ValueHolder(sources: Map[Key[_], Value[_]]) {

  def processSources(): Unit = {
    sources
     .collect { case (_, StringValue(str)) => str }
     .foreach(println)
  }

}
```

#### Scala REPL

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)


    trait Key[+T]

    trait Value[+T]

    case class StringKey(key: String) extends Key[String]
    case class IntKey(key: Int) extends Key[Int]

    case class StringValue(value: String) extends Value[String]
    case class IntValue(value: Int) extends Value[Int]

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined trait Key
defined trait Value
defined class StringKey
defined class IntKey
defined class StringValue
defined class IntValue

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

case class ValueHolder(sources: Map[Key[_], Value[_]]) {

      def processSources(): Unit = {
        sources
         .collect { case (_, StringValue(str)) => str } // extracted string value ready to be operated.
         .foreach(println)
      }

    }

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class ValueHolder
```

#### Output

```
scala> ValueHolder(Map(StringKey("fruit") -> StringValue("apple")))
res2: ValueHolder = ValueHolder(Map(StringKey(fruit) -> StringValue(apple)))

scala> ValueHolder(Map(StringKey("fruit") -> StringValue("apple"))).processSources()
apple
```

In general you can iterate on the key value pairs

given `sources: Map[Key[_], Value[_]]`

#### Process if the value is string value

```
sources.map { case (key, value) =>
  value match {
    case stringValue: StringValue => processValue(stringValue)
    case _ => fallbackValue
  }
}
```

Better way to do this is by using `collect`

```
sources.collect { case (_, value: StringValue) => processValue(value) }
```

Comment: Thanks. That works but it was not what I was looking for (sorry I did not make it clear in the question).  I was wondering whether it's possible to get that without pattern match. The reason is that in the process loop I need to call a method like `def processValue[T](key: Key[T]): SomeOtherType[T]` to get a value of T and do the process to produce some object that related T. Since the call to processValue are the same except the type parameter I want to know whether there is a way to do that directly without pattern match.

Comment: @JackLei you can do anything from here. I do not understand what you can to process. Can you make it clear what you want as end result. for example " I want to process/get 'key' whose string value is 'apple' "

Comment: @JackLei Added more info at the end of the answer. Hope this solves ur problem;

Comment: @JackLei This is the ans for ur question `sources.collect { case (_, value: StringValue) => processValue(value) }`